# Can I customize the Wordpress Query Loop block beyond the options showed in the block editor?

Tags: wordpress

I need to filter posts using tags, but the Query Loop block adopts a "in" method, that is one of the listed tags is enough to select post.
I'd like to use an "and" method, selecting a post only if all the tags are present.
Do you know if there's a way to do this without WP_Query?
If not, can I "inject" a custom WP_Query in a Query Loop block? I'm asking this because I use an already customized query loop which I put on my page via a shortcode I wrote (no plugins).
Thanks in advance, any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.
Luciano

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by registering a variation for the query loop block via JavaScript.

Surprisingly there is a good documentation and example for it here in the core’s docs.

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/10/10/extending-the-query-loop-block/